# C actualize files through makefile all at once

Tags: c, vim, makefile, header-files

I am working on project, where i use couple of .c and .h files.
I created `Makefile` where i actualize executable program based on changes in all of these files.
Problem is, when i use `make`, program is compiled, but when i execute program, it runs without any change. I need to save ( working in vim so `:w` ) all included files, even when i changed only one.
If i don't save all these files, program is compiled, but executes the same thing as it did before change.
Could someone explain me why is that ?

**Makefile code :**

```
CC=gcc  
CFLAGS=-WALL 

execFile: execFile.o functions.h newDataTypes.h
```

Thank you.

Comment: On the face of it, you work with one C file (`execFile.o`) and two headers (`functions.h` and `newDataTypes.h`).  Your makefile doesn't supply the command to execute when the executable is out of date.  When you run `make`, what commands do you see?  Note that the `.o` file is not recompiled from the `.c` if you change a header; you've not said that the `.o` file depends on the the `.h` files.  If you have other object files, they won't be linked either.  In my experience, your `makefile` is sub-minimal.  It might be that you can get away with less information, but I'm not sure I'd trust it.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are not getting execFile updated is because you're NOT updating it. Or at least you don't seem to be in this particular case.

There are many ways to get about doing this. However since you are using gcc and I assume you're using gnu make the following is probably the best solution you can execute<sup>1</sup>.

Given the files:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 user sudo  73 Nov  4 22:54 exeFile.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 user sudo  74 Nov  4 22:54 exeFile.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 user sudo  90 Nov  4 22:55 hello_world.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 user sudo 888 Nov  4 23:03 Makefile
```

> #### cat exeFile.c
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include "exeFile.h"
>
> int main()
> {
>   hello_world();
> }
> ```

---

> #### exeFile.h
>
> ```
> #ifndef _EXEFILE_H
> #define _EXEFILE_H
>
> extern void hello_world();
>
> #endif
> ```

---

> #### hello_world.c
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include "exeFile.h"
>
> void hello_world()
> {
>   printf("Hello World\n");
> }
> ```

you can set up a make file that generates dependencies and ensures that the program will always be compiled correctly:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall
SOURCES=exeFile.c hello_world.c
EXE=exeFile
OBJ=$(SOURCES:%.c=%.o)

DEPDIR := .deps
$(shell mkdir -p $(DEPDIR) >/dev/null)
DEPFLAGS = -MT $@ -MMD -MP -MF $(DEPDIR)/$*.Td


COMPILE.c = $(CC) $(DEPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c
COMPILE.cc = $(CXX) $(DEPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c
POSTCOMPILE = @mv -f $(DEPDIR)/$*.Td $(DEPDIR)/$*.d && touch $@

%.o: %.c
%.o: %.c $(DEPDIR)/%.d
    $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
    $(POSTCOMPILE)

%.o : %.cc
%.o : %.cc $(DEPDIR)/%.d
    $(COMPILE.cc) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
    $(POSTCOMPILE)

%.o : %.cxx
%.o : %.cxx $(DEPDIR)/%.d
    $(COMPILE.cc) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
    $(POSTCOMPILE)

$(DEPDIR)/%.d: ;
.PRECIOUS: $(DEPDIR)/%.d

$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJ) $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJ) $(EXE)

dev-clean: clean
    $(RM) -r $(DEPDIR)

include $(wildcard $(patsubst %,$(DEPDIR)/%.d,$(basename $(SOURCES))))
```

Let's go over the relevant parts about dependencies

#### `DEPDIR =`

This implementation places dependency files into a subdirectory named `.deps` .

#### `$(shell mkdir -p $(DEPDIR) 2>/dev/null)`

GCC does not create subdirectories for output, this line ensures that the DEPDIR directory always exists.

#### `DEPFLAGS = ...`

These are GCC-specific flags which tell the compiler to generate  dependency info.

`-MT $@`

Set the name of the target in the generated dependency file.

`-MMD`

Generate dependency information in addition to compiling. `-MMD` omits system headers from the generated dependencies: if you prefer to preserve system headers as prerequisites, use `-MD` instead.

`-MP`

Adds a make target for each prerequisite in the list, this avoids errors when deleting files.

`-MF $(DEPDIR)/$*.Td`

Write the generated dependency file to a temporary file `$(DEPDIR)/$*.Td` e.g. `hello_world.c` will generate `hello_world.Td` as temp dependency content for use in Makefile.

#### `POSTCOMPILE = ...`

First rename the generated temporary dependency file to the real dependency file. We do this in a separate step to side-step compile errors. Next we explicitly touch the files to avoid a gcc bug.

#### `%.o : %.c`

Delete the built-in rules for building object files from .c files, so that our rule is used instead. Do the same for the other built-in rules.

#### `... $(DEPDIR)/%.d`

Declare the generated dependency file as a prerequisite of the target, so that if it’s missing the target will be rebuilt.

#### `$(DEPDIR)/%.d: ;`

Create a pattern rule with an empty recipe, so that make won’t fail if the dependency file doesn’t exist.

#### `.PRECIOUS: $(DEPDIR)/%.d`

Mark the dependency files precious to make, so they won’t be automatically deleted as intermediate files.

#### `include ...`

Include the dependency files that exist: translate each file listed in `SOURCES` into its dependency file. Use wildcard to avoid failing on non-existent files.

<sup>1</sup> [See Auto-Dependencies Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/#traditional%5D) for details.

Answer (score 0):

**Fix:**

Tell make that the executable depends only on the object file and the object file depends on the header files:

```
execFile: execFile.o
execFile.o: functions.h newDataTypes.h
```

**Explanation:**

In order to build your executable two steps are needed:

- compilation of C source files (that include header files) to produce object files,
- linking of the object files to produce the executable.

So, when changing your header files you must re-compile, that is re-built the object files, not just re-link that would produce the same executable from the same object files.

In your Makefile the dependencies are not properly defined. You did **not** tell make that the **object file** (`execFile.o`) shall be rebuilt when your header files change. Instead, you told it that the **executable** (`execFile`) shall be rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your dependencies are mistaken.  Your executable does not depend on the `.h` header files, as they are using only at compilation time.  The dependencies are normally between `.o` files and `.h` files, as when you modify one `.h` file, the including `.c` file must be compiled to generate the `.o` file.  so in case you have `execFile.o` (which, on lack of complete information, I'll suppose it depends on `execFile.c`, which `#include`s `functions.h` and `newDataTypes.h`, the rule should be:

```
execFile.o: execFile.c functions.h newDataTypes.h
```

As it has been pointed out in other responses, there's no need to write the command to build the `.o` file, as there is a default rule like this:

```
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

(observe there's a `-c` option to the compiler indicating to compile only and don't link, we'll return here below) which means that once you detect the `.o` is outdated (as the dependencies on `.c` and `.h`s mark) it will be compiled with the above command, which result in:

```
gcc -Wall -o execFile.o -c execFile.c
```

making the appropiate compilation.

Other thing is the dependencies of the executable file.  These have to be included, as `make(1)` doesn't know which object files form your final executable.  In this case, assuming you have your program `execFile` depend on `execFile.o` and `a.o`, `b.o` and `c.o`, I normally use to write:

```
execFile_objs = execFile.o a.o b.o c.o
execFile: $(execFile_objs)
     $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(execFile_objs)
```

so any of the `.o`s is changed (because an indirect change in a source file) the whole program is linked again (but only the touched files are compiled)

## NOTE

In the case (not normal) that you have a `Makefile` to create a program that **has only one source file and several include files** you can compile each time the whole thing each time you modify one source file, in this way:

```
execFile: execFile.c functions.h newDataTypes.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ execFile.c
```

This will execute

```
gcc -Wall  -o execFile execFile.c
```

1. Observe that there is no `-c` (compile only, don't link) option in this command.
2. There's no mention of the include files (they are included because of the `#include` directives in the code... and you only state here that the executable depends also (and have to be built) in case any of the `.h` files are modified.

Automatic dependency rules are a little confusing at first, as they induce you to think there are such rules to make any kind of file from any other kind of file (well, there are for `.c -> .o` files, and `.c -> <nothing>` to compile directly to an executable)  normally you have to include dependencies in such cases when your target depends on more files than the automatic rule states.  In such cases, it is **very important** not to include any command, so the compiler selects the automatic rule (when you don't include a command to generate the target, the `make(1)` program tries to use a default rule for it, or nothing at all if you have not included commands, it only assumes your dependencies are indirect through this fake target --- and, as this fake target is not built in the process, it will fail always and be followed)